# Find the natural numbers $n$ for which $\varphi(n)$ is not divisible by $4$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This one is a toughie... I thought I had it, but then my proof didn't work out...

> Let $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}p_3^{\alpha_3}\dots p_r^{\alpha_r}$ be the canonical form of $n$. Therefore:
>
> \begin{align}\varphi(n)&=\varphi(p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}p_3^{\alpha_3}\dots p_r^{\alpha_r})\\&=\varphi(p_1^{\alpha_1})\varphi(p_2^{\alpha_2})\varphi(p_3^{\alpha_3})\dots\varphi(p_r^{\alpha_r})\\&=p_1^{\alpha_1}\left(\frac{p_1-1}{p_1}\right)p_2^{\alpha_2}\left(\frac{p_2-1}{p_2}\right)p_3^{\alpha_3}\left(\frac{p_3-1}{p_3}\right)\dots p_r^{\alpha_r}\left(\frac{p_r-1}{p_r}\right)\end{align}

So from here I figured I'd surmise that $4\mid\varphi(n)$ if there existed an $i$ such that $p_i=2$ and $\alpha_i>3$, or if $p_i=5$... but then it occured to me that $17$ is prime as well, and $17-1=16$, which is divisible by $4$.. So this strategy won't work.

Comment: If $2^3=8|n$ then $4=2^{3-1}|\phi (n)$ . Also if there is a prime factor $p$ , of $n$ , of the form $4k+1$ , then $p-1=4k|\phi (n)$